# How to replace/PUT tabs in a docusign template

Tags: docusignapi

Using the [Api Explorer](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=Templates&operations=update) updating a template with a whole new set of tabs just appends the new tabs on top of the old ones.
The only way we can find to delete old tabs is [this endpoint](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=delete) (with a broken documentation link) which assumes that I would like to carefully send a bespoke delete for each recipient and attach each tabId that isn't relevant. This is incorrect. I have new tabs that are correct, and old tabs that I don't care about.

Workarounds that I'd try, but are also not possible*:

1. delete the template and create a new one (there is no delete template endpoint)
2. delete all tabs in a template before updating the template (I cannot find any bulk delete actions for tabs)
3. list all tabs, and then for-each them into a delete (the [list tabs endpoint](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Templates&tags=TemplateTabs&operations=list) is giving us a 404)
4. move the template to an archive/trash folder and create a new one in it's place. (it is not possible to move a template's folder location using Template Update)
5. update our representation of a tab with the tabId in the response, using X,Y,Page coordinates (coordinates are rounded/quantized, and you'd have to do fuzzy math for every tab to find the closest one, and that's super gross)

How are you supposed to replace all the tabs in a template?

*so far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

Solution to workaround 1: 
The [move envelopes endpoint](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Folders&tags=Folders&operations=moveEnvelopes) also [moves templates](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/moveenvelopes/).

Make sure your `folderId` is "recyclebin"

```
{
  "envelopeIds": [
    "689c311a-118e-447d-a77d-3ea856510a75"
  ]
}
```

Related tip for workaround 4: [(undocumented)](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/folders/folders/moveenvelopes/) a PUT to `https://{baseUrl}/api/accounts/{accountId}/folders/templates`
can move a template's folder

```
 {
    "foldersTemplates": [
        {
            "templateId": "eae13fee-dc17-40f5-aa09-f4d1705c31b6", 
            "folderId": "fb803413-bf4a-4706-9621-03f6915b3305", 
            "newFolderId": "a954b249-04ce-4fde-b564-1afa87c8beab"
        }
    ]
 }
```